# How to link two collapsible menus using HTML and JS

Tags: javascript, html, query-string

Basically, I have two menus on different pages for a website I'm working on. I'm trying to create links between the two that open the corresponding section on the other page.
For example, a collapsible menu with sections A thru D is on "Start" page. A collapsible menu with sections 1 thru 4 is on "Alternate" page. I would like to create a link that is located in the A section on the Start page, which links to the Alternate.html page, opens section 1 on its menu, and scrolls to it. (I included a little drawing, so I hope that makes sense.)
[diagram???](https://i.stack.imgur.com/V9b33.jpg)

(**The collapsible menu by itself works** in the sense that you can click a section to open/close it. I'm only trying to **add** the links between the two.)
So far, I've been trying to use query strings to transfer this information over pages. I've tried using both `document.getElementById` and `document.getElementsByClassName`, and I can get one to work, but not the reverse (ex. section A (start.html) to section 1 (alternate.html) will work, but section 1 (alternate.html) to section A (start.html) will not). For clarification, the page redirect does work both ways, but only the first scroll-and-open sequence recognized of the two works. (ex. the link from one section will take me to the next page, open the correct section, and scroll automatically. The link from the second page will still take me to the previous page, however it will not open or scroll to the corresponding section).

I've been using the following code so far, any help is much appreciated! (CSS, JS and HTML included)

**CSS on BOTH PAGES**

```
.container {
  width: 80%;
  margin: 30px 10%;
}

button.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #D8E9F4;
  border: none;
  outline: 1px solid #698190;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 15px 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  color: #444;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: background-color 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

button.accordion:hover {
  background-color: #698190;
}

button.accordion.is-open {
  background-color: #698190;
}

.accordion-content {
  background-color: #D8E9F4;
  padding: 0 20px;
  max-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  transition: max-height 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.accordion-content.is-open {
    max-height: 100px;
}

/* Please don't change the above code if not necessary. I only included it for some context on how the collapsibles work. */

#a1 {}
#b2 {}
```

**`<head>` HTML with `<script>`, on BOTH PAGES**

```
<head>
    <script>
window.onload = function()  {
    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
    let section = urlParams.get('section');
    if (section === "a1") {
        //click one
        document.getElementById('a1').click();
        //scroll to one
        const element = document.getElementById('a1');
        element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    }
    else if (section === 'b2') {
        //click two
        document.getElementById('b2').click();
        //scroll to two
        const element = document.getElementById('b2');
        element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });
    }
    else {};
};
     </script>
</head>
```

**HTML with `<script>`, on PAGE 1 (`start.html`)**

```
<main>
<div class="container">
    <button class="accordion" style="color: #000D76;" id="a1">Section A</button>
    <div class="accordion-content" style="text-align: center;">
      <p style="line-height: 1; color: #000D76">Text content inside Section A</p>
          <a href="alternate.html?section=a1">Link to section 1 on Page 2</a>
        </div>
     <button class="accordion" style="color: #000D76;" id="b2">Section B</button>
    <div class="accordion-content" style="text-align: center;">
      <p style="line-height: 1; color: #000D76">Text content inside Section B</p>
          <a href="alternate.html?section=b2">Link to section 2 on Page 2</a>
        </div>
</div>
<!--- collapsible javascript --->
        <script>
            var accordions = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");

            for (var i = 0; i < accordions.length; i++) {
              accordions[i].onclick = function() {
                this.classList.toggle('is-open');

                var content = this.nextElementSibling;
                if (content.style.maxHeight) {
                  // accordion is currently open, so close it
                  content.style.maxHeight = null;
                } else {
                  // accordion is currently closed, so open it
                  content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
                }
              }
            }
        </script>
</main>
```

**HTML with `<script>`, on PAGE 2 (`alternate.html`)**

```
<main>
<div class="container">
    <button class="accordion" style="color: #000D76;" id="a1">Section 1</button>
    <div class="accordion-content" style="text-align: center;">
      <p style="line-height: 1; color: #000D76">Text content inside Section 1</p>
          <a href="start.html?section=a1">Link to section A on Page 1</a>
        </div>
     <button class="accordion" style="color: #000D76;" id="b2">Section B</button>
    <div class="accordion-content" style="text-align: center;">
      <p style="line-height: 1; color: #000D76">Text content inside Section 2</p>
          <a href="start.html?section=b2">Link to section B on Page 1</a>
        </div>
</div>
<!--- collapsible javascript --->
        <script>
            var accordions = document.getElementsByClassName("accordion");

            for (var i = 0; i < accordions.length; i++) {
              accordions[i].onclick = function() {
                this.classList.toggle('is-open');

                var content = this.nextElementSibling;
                if (content.style.maxHeight) {
                  // accordion is currently open, so close it
                  content.style.maxHeight = null;
                } else {
                  // accordion is currently closed, so open it
                  content.style.maxHeight = content.scrollHeight + "px";
                }
              }
            }
        </script>
</main>
```

Comment: FWIW, in the provided HTML you don't have any buttons with the **id="b2"**

Comment: @imvain2 thank you lol!! that was just a silly little thing from retyping the code for here but i will double check that i have the ids right in my original!

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise your post title to ask a clear, specific question. Don't add tags, and note that putting a question mark on a statement doesn't make it a question. Also take the [tour].

Comment: Click [edit] then use the `[<>]` snippet editor to make [mcve]s